# getting a cannot read properties on undefined when calling render Rows error on ng mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-decorator

Working with Angular and Angular Material in VS 2019. In the code below I have excluded a lot of code but hope all relevant/pertinent code is present.

I am getting the following error when the code executes line *this.companyTable.renderRows()* in method addDataClick:

[image]

Here is the code:

In my-template.html, I have the following:

```html
<button mat-button (click)="addDataClick()">Company Info</button>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table mat-table #CompanyTable [dataSource]="myDataSource" class="table">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="CompanyName">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company Name </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.companyName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="CompanyAlias">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company Alias </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.companyAlias}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="companyColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: companyColumns;"></mat-row>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In my-interfaces.ts, I have:

```js
export interface ICompany {
  companyName: string;
  companyAlias: string;
}
```

In my component, I have the following (Note: I am not using constructor or ngOnInit):

```js
.....
import { ICompany } from './my-interfaces'
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
.....
@Component({
  selector: ....,
  templateUrl: './my-template.html',
  providers: ....
})
export class myComponent {
  companyColumns: string[] = ['CompanyName', 'CompanyAlias'];
  myDataSource = [];
  @ViewChild('CompanyTable', { static: true }) companyTable: MatTable<ICompany>;
  
  ....

  addDataClick() {
   const aCompany: ICompany = { companyName: "Albertsons", companyAlias: "Acme" };
   this.myDataSource.push(aCompany);
   this.companyTable.renderRows();
  };
}
```

When I hover over this.companyTable at that line, it's not null:
[image]

So I'm baffled as to why I am getting the error on renderRows. It seems as though the ViewChild company variable does not have the proper reference? Any ideas? thanks for any help.

Comment: Note I had some typos that I corrected.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: I have not worked with stackblitz, I will attempt.

Comment: [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-1hhn7t.stackblitz.io) it seems to work :\. [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1hhn7t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Yes your stackblitz does work!!! Unbelievable, obviously there must be something else I am doing wrong, something else interfering. Let me investigate and I will update this post. Many thanks. :)

Comment: if you want more help you could post your code

Comment: Figured it out, it was a typo all along. The datasource name in the component class had an extra letter than the datasource name in the html. Thank you so much for you help @Edoardo, the good that has come out of this is that you have motivated me to explore stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Problem solved - it was a typo all along!! Cleaning up code to post here led me to the correct answer. I had used myDataSource in the html and ts files that I posted.

When I went back to code, my html had dsIdentifiedCompany whereas my ts file used dsI**n**dentifiedCompany.

Thanks to all who viewed and especially to Eduoardo for his time.